# Grep between characters to find error

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I am trying to locate PHP code that will throw error on a update example of PHP code $variable[inside] should be $variable['inside']

im trying to scan through the files using grep to solve them but not much success with the regex ive done

```
grep -iR '\$*\[' ./
```

it shows the bad error but it also shows a bunch of other things that shouldnt be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-P` option for PCRE regex:

```
grep -RP "\\$\\w+\\[[^']+\\]" .
```

or, if `-P` is unavailable for some reason, `-E` for Extended regex:

```
grep -RE "\\$\\w+\\[[^']+\\]" .
```

If you want to check single **and** double quotes:

```
    grep -RP "\\$\\w+\\[[^'\"]+\\]" .
```

or

```
    grep -RE "\\$\\w+\\[[^'\"]+\\]" .
```

Both work fine, the `-i` option is useless here as `\w` includes both cases.

**Explanation:**

```
"           # regex delimiter
\\$         # $ sign, have to be double escaped because of " delimiter
\\w+        # 1 or more word character as a variable name contains only word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
\\[         # openning square bracket
[^']+       # negative character class, 1 or more any character that is not single quote
\\]         # closing square bracket
"           # regex delimiter
```

Comment: Very good answer thank you. I forgot to mention that it should exclude double quotes aswell as single quote, I tried to redo yours but I am not sure how to combine [^']+ with [^"]+ my attempt grep -RE "\\$\\w+\\[[^']+[^"]+\\]" .

Comment: @edward: see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your time to write the answer, the detailed explanation and the edit. Works like a charm.

Comment: @edward: You're welcome, glad it helps.